# Am I rendering from a promise appropriately?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to display the user who is currently logged in.

Few things to note. `user` has an `async` relationship with `profile`. In the `user` model, I have:

```
profile: DS.belongsTo('polymorphable', { polymorphic: true, async: true }),
```

My application route has:

```
model() {
  return this.store.findRecord('user', this.currentSession.get('id'));
},
```

The application template has something like:

```
<div class="profile-photo">
  {{image-tag imageUrl=model.profile.imageUrl}}
</div>
```

The `image-tag` component object has a computed property:

```
src: Ember.computed('imageUrl', {
  get() {
    let imageUrl = this.get('imageUrl');
    console.log(imageUrl.indexOf('imgix') > -1) // returns error
  }
})
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`. This happens because `model.profile` returns a promise and is still resolving by the time the template is rendered.

This is how I got it working. I created an `afterModel` hook:

```
afterModel: function(model, transition) {
  model.get('profile').then(profile => {
    this.controller.set('profile', profile);
  });
},
```

Then in application template I, instead, have:

```
<div class="profile-photo">
  {{#if profile}}
    {{image-tag imageUrl=profile.imageUrl size="mini" class="-small -round"}}
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

Which tells Ember to wait for `profile` to be resolved from the promise.

Does this look "dirty"? Perfectly fine? Or should I consider an alternative approach?

Comment: If profile is not embedded on your payload of user, then your UI needs resolve profile model on rendering. IMHO you need resolve profile on Route in order your UI has not deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, all you need is

```
afterModel: function(model, transition) {
  return model.get('profile');
}
```

Following that, you can access `model.profile` as usual. See the question marked as possible duplicate for more information.